# In Windows Mobile (5/6) SDK, where did windns.h go?

Tags: networking, windows-mobile

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916070.aspx (DnsQuery_W), DNS query libraries are available on Windows Mobile / CE developers for versions 5.0 onwards. Yet, "#include " gives nasty "file not found" errors. What gives?
Strangely enough "dnsapi.lib" is available. Does Microsoft actually expect developers to scavenge the file from somewhere?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted thread [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29287111/dnsqueryw-in-windows-mob.aspx) claims that this API is not actually available in Windows Mobile 5 (and perhaps later?), despite claiming otherwise.  I looked through the Mobile 5 and 6 SDKs, and didn't see this API either, so perhaps the thread's suggestion might work for you:

> If it's a simple host name->IP address
>   (IPv4 or v6), you can use getnameinfo
>   in Winsock.  The DNSQuery_W is only
>   needed if you're doing like a
>   non-A/AAAA query.  If you're doing
>   that, we really don't have any helpers
>   to do that for you from the OS side -
>   sorry.  You may look around to see if
>   there's helper library floating around
>   out there that you may be able to
>   recompile for CE (assuming you're
>   comfortable with whatever licensing
>   agreements they may put on you.)

getnameinfo should be documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923585.aspx) (for Windows Mobile), in case that helps.

Comment: Ideally I wanted full functionality, but A query should suffice. I already solved the problem using gethostbyname. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are really after 'windns.h', I found it in the WM5/WM6/WM6.1 Platform Builders in

\public\common\sdk\inc

The hard part is getting access to the WM Platform Builder if your an ISV.  That I can't help you with.